# Get the name in selectInput widget in R shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm using the selectInput function of shiny package with option groups like this [Output of the selectInput function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB3QI.png)

In the ui.r file i've something like that:

```
ListOfItemsWithNames = list(condition = c("KO","WT"),treatment = c("non","oui"))    
selectInput("Select1_contrast",label="Compare",ListOfItemsWithNames)
```

In the server.R file, when i call input$Select1_contrast I only get the selected value ("oui" for instance).

Is there a way to get both the value an the name of the variable (ie, "oui" and "treatment") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possibility. It uses key-value pairs. Those pairs are allowed according to the documentation of `selectInput`

> **choices** List of values to select from. If elements of the list are named, then that name rather than the value is displayed to the user. This can also be a named list whose elements are (either named or unnamed) lists or vectors. If this is the case, the outermost names will be used as the "optgroup" label for the elements in the respective sublist. This allows you to group and label similar choices. See the example section for a small demo of this feature.

```
addKeys = function(nested_list){
  keyed_nl = list()
  for (a in names(nested_list))
    for (b in (nested_list[[a]]))
      keyed_nl[[a]][[b]] = paste0(a, "-", b)
  keyed_nl
}

ListOfItemsWithNames = list(condition = c("KO", "WT"),
                            treatment = c("non", "oui"))  
keyedList = addKeys(ListOfItemsWithNames)

library(shiny)

shinyApp(    
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("choiceKey", "choose", keyedList),
    textOutput('text')
  ),
  function(input, output, session)
    output$text = renderText(input$choiceKey)
)
```

[image]

As you can see, `input$choiceKey` will give you the category and the choice seperated with `-`. Using `strsplit`, you can get both parts seperately

Answer (score 0):

This should work. In this version, you have a sencond dropdown menu and therefore a second input.

```
library(shiny)

ListOfItemsWithNames = list(condition = c("KO","WT"),treatment = c("non","oui"))  

ui = inputPanel(
  selectInput("category", "choose a category", names(ListOfItemsWithNames )),
  selectInput("choice", "select a choice", ListOfItemsWithNames[[1]])
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "choice", 
      choices = ListOfItemsWithNames[[input$category]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i want to avoid adding a new selectInput. I have to do it many times so my idea is to get the info of the variable and the choice using only one selectInput.